# FBA Active Directory Security Groups Not Working SP 2013

Tags: 2013, security, active-directory, forms-authentication

So I have in active directory one security group, lets call it "Shrpt_Users".

Within SharePoint I have granted this Active directory group read rights to my sub site: "Advertising".

My user SpVisitor is a member of this group but does not get access?!?

I am using Forms Based Authentication.

Comment: When did you enter this user to the AD group? Usually it takes a while (there is timer job that runs and syncs the users) to get pulled into SharePoint. I guess that has not yet happened..

Comment: Unfortunately it was actually yesterday I added it. It was left overnight in the hope that fixed it.